# What causes an automator app from a network share so that normal users can't run it?

Tags: macos, high-sierra, automator, automation

I have an application that I made in Automator which is literally just running a shell command. It's stored on a network share and when I copy it to another mac the root account and admin account can run it, however any other account will not allow me to run it. The message I see it "you can't open the application because it may be damaged or incomplete".
I have run a chown 777 on the file, and chown root:wheel to reset the permissions but still nothing.

The app in question is in the image below, login.app, as shown from a logged on network user which is unable to run the app. Only root and a locally created admin user can run this app.

If i recreate the app and re-save it I can use it on all users.
What technical documentation can I read on what the damaged error considers so I can adapt my Automator App to run?

[image]

Comment: Feel free to post a basic example of what the action looks like - screen shot is fine if no one has an answer in the next two or three days. It might be something quick to point out or it might depend on someone reproducing your test case and debugging a bit...

Comment: Have you tried opening and re-saving in Automator? Is the network share a Mac file system, or not? It's possible some extended attributes might have got lost. However, why that shouldn't affect admins, I don't know.

Comment: I opened it, duplicated it and re-saved it,I could then run the duplicated app with no problem as any user. I'm gonna have to do this on every mac though which is why I'd sooner fix what's messed up with the original. However if I can't fix the original then this is certainly a good workaround, thank you for your suggestion..

Comment: Are both Macs running the same version of macOS?

Comment: Great image. I was thinking you would show what you coded in Automator in case that was the problem. This might help someone understand you call the app login keeps for editing.

Comment: That was me taking you a little to literally, I thought you meant the action of opening the file. Although re-reading what you wrote, it makes sense to me now that you meant workflow action.